# Excel VBA to lock row if certain cell IS NULL

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to use this code on the official microsoft [blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/lock-cell-row-range-when-a-specific-cell-is-not-empty/m-p/3295628) for the following logic:
If there’s any value in column C (not null) then make the rows editable (unlocked)
If not they cannot be edited (locked)
e.g. c3 not null d3->k3 editable if c3 null d3->k3 locked

code is as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    If Not Intersect(Range("C3:C1000"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        For Each rng In Intersect(Range("C3:C1000"), Target)
            rng.EntireRow.Locked = (rng.Value <> "")
        Next rng
    End If
End Sub
```

My issues are the following:

I want the VBA to work when the user adds another row to the bottom of the table e.g. in the highlighted yellow cells
i.e. in c9, c10, c11 c12….

[image]

How do I accomplish this using the code?

Comment: What is not working with the code you have shown.  It should do as you want.

Comment: it is still letting me edit the rows if the cells in the C columns are empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const PW As String = "Secret" 'use Const for fixed values
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range, doLock As Boolean

    Set rng = Intersect(Me.Range("C3:C1000"), Target)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Me.Unprotect Password:=PW
        For Each c In rng.Cells
            doLock = Len(c.Value) = 0
            With c.EntireRow.Range("D1:K1") 'D1:K1 is relative to the row...
                .Locked = doLock
                If doLock Then  'apply/clear range fill
                    .Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200) 'grey out locked cells
                Else
                    .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone 'no fill
                End If
            End With
        Next c
        Me.Protect Password:=PW
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I have added the code and took away the password protected sections (I just need it to lock/not allow the user to insert anything in the row) but I still can

Comment: Locking has no effect if the sheet is not protected.

Comment: ok, thanks I did not know... added exactly as above but still doesn't lock the rows or asks for psw if the c column is empty- e.g. removed value in C3 but could still add/remove values in all cells of that row (d3 to k3)

Comment: Working for me - are you sure events are enabled ?

Comment: Upvoted - kind of works now but want the users to be able to still edit the C column (if empty I would still like them to add/remove values if there are any -shouldn't be psw protected) its just the table that needs to be locked/unlocked + with the current code the whole sheet seems to lock (any cell outside the table) when a value from the C column is removed

Comment: By default all cells on a sheet are Locked, so once you protect the sheet those cells are non-editable. If you want users to be able to edit Col C then you first need to unlock the cells in that range.